# "Who you don't know their name" vs "Whose name you don't know"

Tags: spoken-english, informal-language, non-standard-english

From [urbandictionary.com](https://www.urbandictionary.com/author.php?author=west_side_thug_life):
**(1)** *G - word used to call someone who you don't know their name*
my variant:
**(2)** *G - word used to call someone whose name you don't know*

As far as I understand, entry (1) is ungrammatical and in formal writing we must use only "whose..." as in entry (2).

But I'm interested, is it natural to use "who...", as in (1), in speech?

Comment: Per FumbleFinger's interpretation of your question, can you please edit to clarify if you are talking about the use of "G" or the use of "who" and "whose" in the UD entry?

Comment: @BadZen The question is about the possibility of using "_someone who you don't know their name_" instead of "_someone whose name you don't know_" in speech.

Comment: Word of caution… never use urbandictionary as a source for 'real' English. It is not written by experts but by the general population, who may be of questionable skill.

Comment: @DoneWithThis. thank you for your clever comment

Comment: I agree that you've version is preferred. Not an answer but just an aside — they may also have been going for _"Word used to call someone **when** you don't know their name"_  (which was my first reading of it, assuming a typo)

Comment: It's not explicitly stated in the question, but the answers could also be improved by considering another alternative: "word used to call someone that you don't know the name of". Some people will (despite the evidence of consistent use of such constructions by "good" authors) say you shouldn't use it in formal writing because it ends the sentence with a preposition, but such constructions are actually well established in all contexts

Comment: @Loviii - the people who write on "urban dictionary" are often near illiterate.  It's really confusing what you're asking?   If you look at writing samples from near-illiterate people .,. what is your point?  Are you asking "Is it common for near-illiterate people to write X Y Z" .. or ?

Comment: @Fattie too many emotions, Fattie. This is not a TV show or something. Please chill a little bit ;)

Comment: @Fattie I suspect an ELL is assuming that it's mostly written by people who speak English better than they do. Unfortunately, many native speakers don't know grammar well.

Comment: @DoneWithThis. "It is not written by experts" is something that could be said about this site here, too. It's probably still better than UD, but not by far, when you start reading beyond the accepted answers ;) Luckily, there's a voting system.

Comment: @thymaro - yeah - at least there's a visible element of peer review here, which tends to work in the main. …whereas urban dictionary has the editorial values of… facebook ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This type of construction is incorrect, but still somewhat common, at least in Canada and the US. It is used *self-consciously* where the speaker cannot figure out a grammatical way to phrase something complex, so they use a purposefully incorrect phrasing that anyone can understand, and makes a joke out of the fact that it's difficult to phrase.

In your example, it's easy enough to rephrase it correctly with "whose", so the original author was just being lazy or humorous. So let's take an example where it's actually difficult to put a good sentence together with the intended meaning.

Let's say you want to play a guessing game where someone shows you an object, and you will guess where they bought it. You could say it in more than one sentence:

> Show me something of yours. Make sure I don't know where you bought this thing.

Trying to combine these two into one sentence with a relative clause is not something most native speakers can do without stopping to think about it, so they might choose to say something ungrammatical like the following:

> *Show me something of yours that I don't know where you bought it.
> *Show me something of yours where I don't know where you bought it.

Incidentally, there's at least one way to say it correctly, but it sounds so pedantic that many people would prefer to make a grammar error:

> Show me something of yours that is such that I don't know where you bought it.

Oooof.

So bottom line, no, the grammar in the Urban Dictionary definition isn't considered correct in any variety of English, and would get marked down in an academic essay, but is common and easily understood by anyone.

Comment: I'm not sure it's *always* used self-consciously. People vary a lot in how much attention they pay to their own usage. But it absolutely happens to people that the only way they can think of to express something violates their own intuitions of correctness, and this is a good example.

Comment: I agree with @Mark that this is far from always self-conscious. It’s not at all an uncommon pattern to hear from younger AmE speakers in my experience. Relative _whose_ is, I suspect, slowly becoming obsolescent in AmE, and many young speakers use it rarely, if ever, actually _preferring_ a construction like this one, despite it resulting in a [syntactic island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wh-movement#Extraction_islands).

Comment: While I agree with the principle, to me "Show me something of yours that I don't know where you bought" (without the final *it*) is natural and looks grammatical. Although maybe it changes the semantics a tiny bit. Or "... that you bought somewhere I don't know". Even if we pretend *whose* isn't a word for the original sentence, "word used to call someone who has a name you don't know" seems acceptable.

Comment: "In your example, it's easy enough to rephrase it correctly with "whose", so the original author was just being lazy or humorous." ... Or, perhaps, it could have been written by someone who isn't very skilled with English?

Comment: The OP things that "urban dictionary" is an edited, or something, source of English corpus. Any answer is very unhelpful that doesn't first point out the obvious, random typing on "urban dictionary" is completely meaningless and valueless. (Except as a kind of historical object.)

Comment: @Fattie Thanks for the comment. The OP knows Urban Dictionary isn't a valid source. They had already responded to a comment to that effect on the original question when I posted this answer.

Answer (score 6):

(1) Is indeed ungrammatical, and not natural in speech.  That isn't to say that it would never occur (native speakers make errors all the time).  But I would not judge it to be grammatically correct English.

Contrast that "Someone who plays tennis".  This relative clause is correct. And even "Someone who Peter plays at tennis".

The problem seems to be that in the relative clause, the noun being modified needs to be either the subject or the object

> An apple that I ate  (Object: I ate an apple)  // An apple that grew on a tree  (subject: An apple grew on a tree)

But "*An apple that I ate a pear.  is not correct

And for the same reason "*Someone who you don't know their name" is not correct. And moreover is not acceptable in casual spoken English.

Comment: The noun being modified does not need to be the subject or object if there is an appropriate preposition, even a stranded one: _a word used to call someone you don't know the name of_ is fine. What is jarring about 1) is the pronoun _their_. This would be standard in some languages, but is not grammatical in English (though as you said, I'm sure some people would say it quite happily).

Comment: "Someone *whom* Peter plays at tennis"...   and the relative pronoun can be omitted: "Someone Peter plays at tennis" is perfectly OK.

Comment: Although it's ungrammatical, I disagree that it isn't natural. As gotube said, it occurs quite frequently.

Answer (score 4):

"But I'm interested, is it natural to use "who...", as in (1), in speech?"

Natural for whom? There are a lot of Americans who would use the construction. Then again, lots of native English speakers use technically ungrammatical language. For instance, "would have" and "could have" are commonly contracted to "would've" and "could've", and some people re-expand those to "would of" and "could of".

Comment: I'd say this is something different: this is a spelling error. They don't know who to spell it and becasue "would of" would sound basically the same, they make the mistake. And, on a side note, I wouldn't say "some people", it's much more like "many people", sadly. :-)

Comment: @Gábor - I have to disagree. I'm sure the people who make this mistake are perfectly capable of spelling "have". They really think that "of" is correct.